# When do you use #getChildRoutes from React-router to set dynamic routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Reading the [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#getcomponentsnextstate-callback), when would you need to use `getChildRoutes`? When would dynamic routing happen? I thought when you set all your components, the routes will be set there and then - when would it change dynamically?

> Same as childRoutes but asynchronous and receives partialNextState.
>   Useful for code-splitting and dynamic route matching (given some state
>   or session data to return a different set of child routes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example: say you want to have some part of your app available only to authorized users, you would then load some of the routes asynchronously after the user logs in.